# is it alright if Windows Service is paused but working?

Tags: java, service, window, nssm

I created a window service using NSSM, when I start it, it works once and displays warning:

> Could not resume ListenerNodeJS Service on Local Computer. Service did
>   not return an error. This could be an internal Windows error or an
>   internal service error.  If the problem persists, contact your system
>   administrator.

Service goes into pause state.

So I setup the service to automatically restart so it may work again every 2 minutes. Is it OK to make Window Service work like this?

Comment: No, it's meaningless. It is *either* paused *or* working.

Comment: then can you give me a good service wrapper other than Java Service Wrapper because it's really not working on me :(